# How to connect Salesforce to Quickbooks?

Tags: integration, force, quickbooks

I am wondering is there a way to connect Salesforce with Quickbooks for free. I have seen a few applications that do the job however, they are just trails and must be bought. Is there any way that I could do it without using a third party application and could usig mapping?

Comment: Here's the Quickbooks API manual. Hope this helps.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0050_quickbooks_api

Answer (score 0):

You could use any integration tool from appexchange & choose free version . Some tools have free version which support one way integration between salesforce & quickbooks like customr sync & invoice sync .